# Is it possible to upgrade my Time Capsule hard disk and keep the backup(s) from the original?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, upgrade, time-capsule, migration

Can I upgrade my Time Capsule to a larger internal drive and keep my original backup(s)?

I'm aware you can drop in the new disk, the restore it as a new TC using AirPort Utility, and I'm also aware you can migrate backup(s) from an existing TimeMachine drive to a new one - but I want to do both: I want to replace the 500gb drive in my Time Capsule (2nd gen, 2009) to a 1tb drive, and I want to keep the existing backup(s) from the 500gb to the new drive, so everything is as it was, just with a larger internal drive.

I understand it's not as simple as swapping the drive, restoring it as a new TC and then using CCC to copy the data from the original drive, so is there a solution to what I want to achieve? Basically I want to upgrade the original TC drive to a larger one and not lose my previous backup(s).

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable for sure.

First, you need to transfer files and then change your HDD.

This Apple tutorial shows how to transfer the Time Machine backups. 
[Transfer Time Machine backups from one backup disk to another](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380)

Here in this iFixit link, it's a how-to tutorial for the HDD Replacement. 
[Apple Time Capsule Model A1302 Hard Drive Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Apple+Time+Capsule+Model+A1302+Hard+Drive+Replacement/2750)

I hope you get it done!